# How to test an Observable<boolean>

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a condition that returns an Observable like the following:

app.component.ts

```js
  import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    
  export class ProductComponent implements OnInit

        ProductListLength: Number;
        isProductListEmpty: Observable<boolean>; 
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {

        if(this.ProductListLength === 0)
        this.isProductListEmpty = new Observable((observer) => observer.next(true))
    } 
        else {
        this.isProductListEmpty = new Observable((observer) => observer.next(false))
    }
```

I tried to run these test cases:

app.component.spec.ts

```js
it('should return true when List is empty', () => {

   component.productListLength = 0
   fixture.detectChanges()

   expect(component.isProductListEmpty).toBeTrue()
})

it('should return false when List not empty', () => {

   component.productListLength = 2
   fixture.detectChanges()

   expect(component.isProductListEmpty).toBeFalse()
})
```

But running ng test I receive this:
**ERROR: Expected Observable({_isScalar: false, _subscribe: Function}) to be true**

How to properly test these cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your tests async by using the argument to the tests to tell it when it's done:

```
it('should return true when List is empty', (done) => {

   component.productListLength = 0
   fixture.detectChanges()

   component.isProductListEmpty.subscribe(val => {
     expect(val).toBeTrue();
     done();
   });
})
```

Comment: Ty. worked for me. but now it is showing that both tests expects to be false. Even the first one.

Comment: i'd need to see the actual error messages.

Comment: First test I got **Error: Expected false to be true**.I put a `console.log(productListLength)` inside the subscribe and the value still 0. I noticed aswell that the `fixture.detectChanges()` does not make difference if I remove it. I can paste the entire test spec if you want.

Comment: it's not saying the tests expects to be false, it's saying it expects to be true, but is getting false. aka, the test is working and you have a bug in your code. I'm guessing it's because you for some reason are reassigning observables in `ngOnInit` which only runs one time in a component lifecycle and not on change detection cycles. so changing the value for `productListLength` isn't going to change the underlying observable after the initialization hook runs, but you're expecting it to

Comment: Yeah sorry, I misspoke. I had to remove the detectChanges() from my beforeEach block and call manually. Then expectations gets right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from the observable.  You can subscribe to it or use async await.  Something like the following should work (not tested).

```js
it('should return false when List not empty', async () => {

   component.productListLength = 2
   fixture.detectChanges();
   const res = await component.isProductListEmpty.toPromise();
   expect(res).toBeFalse()
})
```

Edit (should solve the timeout issue)

```js
it('should return false when List not empty', async () => {

   component.productListLength = 2
   component.ngOnInit();
   const res = await component.isProductListEmpty.toPromise();
   expect(res).toBeFalse()
})
```

Comment: tried with yours and got  **Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms**. I think that should work too, prolly is something specific on my code.

Comment: Hmm, does your test file call `ngOnInit` at all?  If not then the observable will never be initialised.

Answer (score 0):

To add to `Daniel Douglas` answer, I think you need to use the `take` operator.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

it('should return false when List not empty', async () => {

   component.productListLength = 2
   fixture.detectChanges();
   const res = await component.isProductListEmpty.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
   expect(res).toBeFalse()
})
```

We have to `take(1)` because we take the first emission and then convert to a promise. You got the timeout error because if you didn't take the first emission, the promise would never resolve (it would hang).

I also hope that the `fixture.detectChanges()` is the first one you're calling in the test suite to call `ngOnInit` for you. If not, you will have to manually call `ngOnInit` every time you update `isProductListEmpty`.

Comment: Ty sir. Worked for me. I needed to remove the fixture.detectChanges() from the beforeEach block and call manually tho. Cause both was returning false. Idk if one can override another.